# Laravel - get records between two dates with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I use Laravel and I want to get records between two dates. In frontend I use daterangepicker and I write:

```
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  var start = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  var end = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

 $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
                url   : '{{url()}}/getOrders',
data: {start: start, end: end},
                cache : false,

                beforeSend : function() {
                    console.log('krece');
                },

                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },

                error : function() {

                }
            });


});
```

so I try to send start and end date and get dates between and in Laravel I have :

route:

```
Route::post('/getOrders', 'OrdersController@getOrders');
```

and in OrdersController:

```
    public function getOrders(Request $request) {
    $start = $request->start;
    $end = $request->end;

//ALSO NEED QUESRY WHICH WILL FETCH ROWS BETWEEN DATES
//$orders = Auth::user()->orders()->get(); ... ...

    return $orders;

    }
```

now when I choose some dates in daterangepicker I get:

```
 POST http://localhost:8888/getOrders 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What is a problem?

Off cource in header I put:

```
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

How to get records between dates ith Laravel and jquery ajax?

Comment: created_at is the comlumn name in orders table ...

Answer (score 1):

You can take the use of `whereBetween()` to get results between dates:

```
$orders = Auth::user()
            ->orders()
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For the query you can do as:

```
$orders = Auth::user()->orders()
                      ->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $end))
                      ->get();
```

And for the `500 (Internal Server Error)` you can check your `laravel.log` file.

Comment: laravel.log say : ... ...te\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 C:\wamp\www\dine\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 C:\wamp\www\dine\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 C:\wamp\www\dine\public\index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 {main}

Comment: The error is not readable here in comments. You can add it in your queation or an image also works.